# About the underlying storage of std::basic_string

Tags: c++11, memory, stdstring

After reading through the description about `std::basic_string` on cppreference, I'm uncertain about the following two questions regarding the underlying storage of `std::basic_string`:

1) Since C++11, does the contiguity of `std::basic_string` extends to the terminating null character? Note that `str[str.size()]` returns a reference to a terminating null character. But I want to make sure whether this is the one after `str[str.size() - 1]`.

2) Since C++11, `data()` and `c_str()` become equivalent. But does it hold that `data() == c_str() == &front()`?

Any quotation from the standard would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes and yes, to both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **21.4.1.7** `basic_string` accessors
>
> `const charT* c_str() const noexcept;`
>
> `const charT* data() const noexcept;`
>
> *1* Returns: A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`.
>
> *2* Complexity: constant time.

This effectively requires that the terminating `NUL` be stored contiguously together with the character sequence (it forces an additional requirement on `operator[]` that `s[s.size()]` not do anything fancy, though the plain text of **21.4.5** appears to give it some latitude).

It also explicitly requires that `s.c_str() == &s[0]`, which in turn means that `s.c_str() == &s.front()` (`front()` is defined as `operator[](0)`).

Comment: Yes, yes. What had been troubling me is the statement that `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` for any n in [0, s.size()). But this turns out to be a flaw of the iterator (`s.begin() + s.size()` is a special off-the-end iterator and can do something fancy), not the contiguity :)